# Best way to read a config file in bash

Tags: bash

What is the best way to read a config file in bash?
For example, you have a script and aren't willing to fill in all the config manually each time you call the script.

Edit 1:
I think I didn't make it clear, so: what I want is... I have a configfile which is like

```
variable_name value  
variable_name value ...
```

and I want to read that. I know I could just grep it for the arguments I'm looking for or so... but maybe there's a more intelligent way :)

Comment: You'll have to show what kind of configuration you mean. Provide an example.

Comment: See also [a very similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/175648/143088) on the Unix & Linux StackExchange.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

As mbiber said, `source` another file. For example, your config file (say `some.config`) would be:

```
var1=val1
var2=val2
```

And your script could look like:

```
#! /bin/bash

# Optionally, set default values
# var1="default value for var1"
# var1="default value for var2"

. /path/to/some.config

echo "$var1" "$var2"
```

---

The many files in `/etc/default` usually serve as configuration files for other shell scripts in a similar way. A very common example from posts here is `/etc/default/grub`. This file is used to set configuration options for GRUB, since `grub-mkconfig` is a shell script that sources it:

```
sysconfdir="/etc"
#…
if test -f ${sysconfdir}/default/grub ; then
  . ${sysconfdir}/default/grub
fi
```

---

If you really must process configuration of the form:

```
var1 some value 1
var2 some value 2
```

Then you could do something like:

```
while read var value
do
    export "$var"="$value"
done < /path/to/some.config
```

(You could also do something like `eval "$var=$value"`, but that's riskier than sourcing a script. You could inadvertently break that more easily than a sourced file.)

Comment: That's a great way, i could use sed substitute whitespace for "="

Comment: There's one more thing... what if a clueless user adds rm -rf / to the script? This script could just kill the computer... any ideas?

Comment: @IcyIcyIce Just don't. Why can't you write it with `=` from the start?

Comment: @IcyIcyIce That's how it's supposed to be. You can use shell code in the various files in `/etc/default` - and mostly to good use. If your clueless user has access to configuration for something running as root, it's already a lost cause.

Comment: this is something I have to do in school. I think I'll do it with the source... It's just that they always test all the shit and I want as many points as possible. But I'll say that only priviledged users should have access to the script and try it that way. Thanks guys :)

Comment: And there's a format I have to use. So I'll have to use sed every time I load it. But whatever

Comment: @IcyIcyIce get your teachers to clarify what they want. A part of learning to develop software is getting to know the requirements clearly.

Comment: @IcyIcyIce see update.

Comment: That one is really nice

Comment: For anyone wanting to do this and aren't 100% sure there will be a file but don't want the error to show, redirect the error using `. /path/to/some.config 2>/dev/null`

Comment: When you source a file, you are executing whatever commands exists in it. It may be a security risk, so be aware of that.

Answer (score 10):

Use `source` or `.` to load in a file.

```
source /path/to/file
```

or

```
. /path/to/file
```

It's also recommended to check if the file exists before loading it because you don't want to continue running your script if a configuration file is not present.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, I am not the `bash` specialist here, but the concept should not be different in whatever language you use:

#### An example

In the example below, you can use a (very) basic script to either *set* a string, or *print* a string, as set in your config file:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# argument to set a new string or print the set string
arg=$1
# possible string as second argument
string=$2
# path to your config file
configfile="$HOME/stringfile"

# if the argument is: "set", write the string (second argument) to a file
if [ "$arg" == "set" ]
then
echo "$string" > $configfile 
# if the argunment is "print": print out the set string, as defined in your file
elif [ "$arg" == "print" ]
then 
echo "$( cat $configfile )"
fi
```

#### Then

- To set a string into your config file:

  ```bsh
  $ '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/test.sh' set "Een aap op een fiets, hoe vind je zoiets?"
  ```
- Subsequently, to print out the string, as defined in your "configfile":

  ```bsh
  $ '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/test.sh' print
  Een aap op een fiets, hoe vind je zoiets?
  ```

Of course, in a real applied script, you need to add a lot of stuff to make sure the arguments are correct, decide what to do when input is incorrect, settings file does not exist etc, but:

*This is the basic idea*

Comment: thanks, i'm just updating the question i think i didnt make it clear... but in simple cases this would work like a charm ofc

Answer (score 3):

I am using this one...

```
#!/bin/bash

CFG_FILE=/etc/test.conf
CFG_CONTENT=$(cat $CFG_FILE | sed -r '/[^=]+=[^=]+/!d' | sed -r 's/\s+=\s/=/g')
eval "$CFG_CONTENT"
```

Conf file is parsed with sed and then evaluated as simple variable asignments

First sed parsing key values (supports also = surrounded with spaces)

Second sed removes spaces around = sign for valid variable asignment

Futher sed treatment can be added

All other not matching text in conf file will be removed (including # or ; commentary and other)

Be aware that single line shell commands can be also evaluated from this config file!

Comment: [Useless use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat). Why do you invoke `sed` twice back-to-back? You can chain `sed` commands like so: `sed -r '/[^=]+=[^=]+/!d;s/\s+=\s/=/g'`

Comment: Also, this `sed` command will generate an empty output for the sample configuration file entries in the question. -1

Comment: Another possible improvement: use the `.` command and process redirection instead of temporary variables to hold the output of the sub-process: `. <(sed ... "$CFG_FILE")`

Comment: Of course my example uses key=value like config file. It is better practise than "key value". Using key=value my example works. Your chaining of sed commands is better, I admit, but source command expects file so we can use: `eval $(sed -r '/[^=]+=[^=]+/!d;s/\s+=\s/=/g' "$CFG_FILE")`, which is way better to understand what there is going on.

Comment: Yes, `.` expects a file and process substitution is expanded to a file. `. <(echo echo foo)` works just as expected in Bash v4.3.11. In small examples it probably won't matter. I'd rather not pass multiple kilobytes through command substitution though.

Answer (score 2):

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# parse the ini like $0.$host_name.cnf and set the variables
# cleans the unneeded during after run-time stuff. Note the MainSection
# courtesy of : http://mark.aufflick.com/blog/2007/11/08/parsing-ini-files-with-sed
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
doParseConfFile(){
    # set a default cnfiguration file
    cnf_file="$run_unit_bash_dir/$run_unit.cnf"

    # however if there is a host dependant cnf file override it
    test -f "$run_unit_bash_dir/$run_unit.$host_name.cnf" \
    && cnf_file="$run_unit_bash_dir/$run_unit.$host_name.cnf"

    # yet finally override if passed as argument to this function
    # if the the ini file is not passed define the default host independant ini file
    test -z "$1" || cnf_file=$1;shift 1;


    test -z "$2" || ini_section=$2;shift 1;
    doLog "DEBUG read configuration file : $cnf_file"
    doLog "INFO read [$ini_section] section from config file"

    # debug echo "@doParseConfFile cnf_file:: $cnf_file"
    # coud be later on parametrized ...
    test -z "$ini_section" && ini_section='MAIN_SETTINGS'

    doLog "DEBUG reading: the following configuration file"
    doLog "DEBUG ""$cnf_file"
    ( set -o posix ; set ) | sort >"$tmp_dir/vars.before"

    eval `sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*\=[[:space:]]*/=/g' \
        -e 's/#.*$//' \
        -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//' \
        -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' \
        -e "s/^\(.*\)=\([^\"']*\)$/\1=\"\2\"/" \
        < $cnf_file \
        | sed -n -e "/^\[$ini_section\]/,/^\s*\[/{/^[^#].*\=.*/p;}"`

    ( set -o posix ; set ) | sort >"$tmp_dir/vars.after"

    doLog "INFO added the following vars from section: [$ini_section]"
    cmd="$(comm -3 $tmp_dir/vars.before $tmp_dir/vars.after | perl -ne 's#\s+##g;print "\n $_ "' )"
    echo -e "$cmd"
    echo -e "$cmd" >> $log_file
    echo -e "\n\n"
    sleep 1; printf "\033[2J";printf "\033[0;0H" # and clear the screen
}
#eof func doParseConfFile
```

Answer (score 0):

one more option is to use ini format and manage config with [crudini](https://www.pixelbeat.org/programs/crudini/).

install crudini on Ubuntu: `sudo apt install crudini`

usage example:

```
$ crudini --set example.ini "section name" "value name" "foo bar"
$ cat example.ini
[section name]
value name = foo bar
$ value_name=$(crudini --get example.ini "section name" "value name")
$ echo "$value_name"
foo bar
$
```

i would avoid `source` in my scripts cause it will execute arbitrary code.

**source.config**

```
var1=val1; echo rm -rf /
```

sourcing this file will run `echo rm -rf /`